# Jump to specific character in a line in VI

Tags: vim, vi

In VI, I know that if you do

```
:some_number
```

and hit enter, you will jump to the line specified by "some_number".  Is there an equivalent for jumping to a specific character in a single line?

Basically, I have a large csv and there is some characters that are breaking the parser; so I have to debug it.

I'm getting an error message that basically says "unexpected character on line XXX character YYY".

I know how to get to XXX but how do I get to YYY?

Comment: to go to line 300 , char 20  do:    `300G20|`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you want the cursor on a particular column, the command *`n|`*, where *`n`* is the column number, and `|` is the pipe symbol, puts the cursor on the intended column in the line the cursor already appears on.

Comment: Also useful: `t`/`T` to go to the character before the given character, and `;` to repeat the previous `t`/`T`/`f`/`F`.

Comment: And `,` to go in the opposite direction using the same previous letter.

Comment: Just a note to readers after 2022-04-15, this has been edited so drastically, it's really no longer my answer. This has happened to me a lot. I'm about to delete my account, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to go to the 12th character on a line:

```
12|
```

For the 6th character in the line:

```
6|
```